# Changing the Background Tint of an ImageButton using a float value

Tags: android

I know its possible to change the background color using:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.blendARGB(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#000000"), offset));
```

Is there a similar way to change the Background Tint of an `ImageButton` using a float value

I am using a SlidingUpLayout which returns a float value of its position

```
public void onPanelSlideChange(float offset) {
    setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.blendARGB(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#000000"), offset)
}
```

I want an `ImageButton` to change colour using the offset value so as the Sliding Layout Moves the image buttons will change colour accordingly with the offset value

Comment: You can try using `ceil` and `floor` and change your color accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I Have a solution, because all shades between black and white have the same R,G,B values i use the getColor(float offset) method to change the Hue dynamically, I Just thought there would be a simpler solution, Hopefully this will be of some use to someone...

```
public void onPanelSlideChange(float offset) {
    int color = getColor(offset);
    view.setColorFilter(color, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}

public int getColor(Float value) {
    int color = android.graphics.Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255); // WHITE
    if (value != null && value >= 0 && value <= 1) {
        if (value == 0) return color;
        else {
            int RGB = (int) ((int) 255 - (255 * value));
            return android.graphics.Color.argb(255, RGB, RGB, RGB);
        }
    }
    return color;
}
```